# how to get translate x , y and scale x , y from transform string,it is "translate(123,343.32) scale(0.8,0.89)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, svg

how to get translate x , y and scale x , y from transform string,it is `translate(123,343.32) scale(0.8,0.89)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG comes with a [DOM API](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransform) which can get these values...

```js
var g = document.getElementById("g");
console.log(g.transform.animVal[0].matrix.e + ", " + g.transform.animVal[0].matrix.f);
console.log(g.transform.animVal[1].matrix.a + ", " + g.transform.animVal[1].matrix.d);
```

```html
<svg>
 <g id="g" transform="translate(123,343.32) scale(0.8,0.89)"/>
</svg>
```